# Unable to See Code Changes to Published ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to make changes to an internally hosted site. Changes made to the aspx design seem to work, and I am publish them to the server, but any changes that I make to the "code-behind" files seem to do nothing. I have tried cleaning and building the solution, but these steps haven't proven effective either. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you upload the correct library to the `bin` folder on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
and delete the file with the name of your application, then rebuild